# Is there a way to style individual cell using react-table based on the value?

Tags: reactjs, react-table-v7

I want to style individual cell in react-table but I am not able to do so.

```
const MOCK_DATA = [
  {
    amount: 1000,
    status: `SUCCESS`,
    updatedAt: 1629181927,
  },
  {
    amount: 2000,
    status: `FAILED`,
    updatedAt: 1629181927,
  },
];
```

```
export const COLUMNS = [
  {
    Header: 'Date',
    accessor: 'transactionDate',
  },
  {
    Header: 'Amount',
    accessor: 'amount',
  },
  {
    Header: 'Status',
    accessor: 'status',
  },
];
```

This is the jsx:

```
 <tbody {...getTableBodyProps()}>
        {rows.map(row => {
          prepareRow(row);
          return (
            <tr {...row.getRowProps()}>
              {row.cells.map(cell => (
                <td {...cell.getCellProps()}>{cell.render('Cell')}</td>
              ))}
            </tr>
          );
        })}
      </tbody>
```

Let suppose I want to change the color of the cell to green or red based on the status of the data how can I achieve that?

Note:

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can make use of the custom cell render option in `react-table` .

```
  {
        Header: "Status",
        accessor: "status",
        Cell: (props) => {
          return (
            <p style={{ color: props.value === "SUCCESS" ? "green" : "red" }}>
              {props.value}
            </p>
          );
        }
      }
```

[Working Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/cool-dew-2w390?file=/src/App.js)

when there are multiple status and needs to show different color for each status we can maintain a map .

```
const statusColorMap =  {
  SUCCESS: 'green',
  FAILED: 'red',
  PENDING: 'yellow'
  // etc 
}
```

Now we can do this

```
<p style={{ color: statusColorMap[props.value] }}>{props.value}</p>;
```

Comment: This actually worked thanks, but one last question, what if the status has three values and wants to add one more color like yellow based on the third condition?

Comment: updated my answer and sandbox to cover for multiple statuses

Answer (score 0):

You can use `status` to define `class` like this.

```
 <tr {...row.getRowProps()} className={row.status === 'SUCCESS' ? 'active': 'warning'}>
              {row.cells.map(cell => (
                <td {...cell.getCellProps()}>{cell.render('Cell')}</td>
              ))}
            </tr>
```